# How to get Google translate to work for textboxes in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-translate

I have an asp.net website in which I have used google translate to translate the text from English to Hindi or Marathi.Here is a part of the code:

```
<head>
<meta name="google-translate-customization" 
content="3280487709591956-dc3fc45d489f056a-g5378ebab0cbcd0a4-12"/>   
</head>

<div id="google_translate_element">            
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestion" runat="server" Height="101px" TextMode="MultiLine"
Width="627px" meta:resourcekey="txtQuestionResource1" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:TextBox>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit()
{
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', 
    layout:google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE }
    ,'google_translate_element');
 }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js? cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
</script>
```

Now, when I select the language say Hindi, what happens is that, the entire website text including the text in labels,dropdownlists etc. gets translated but the textbox text remains as it is.I want the textbox text to change as well.Kindly let me know where I am going wrong and how to get the textbox text translated ?

Answer (score 0):

I think in this situation you should probably take a look at angular.js, it will suit your your needs best.

You can wrap the service layer up in a model and put it in a controller so you can make it responsive for your controls on your page.

https://angularjs.org/